# How to clone class in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I want to create a clone of a class in my test and then monkey patch one of the functions in the test. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean "clone a class"? do you mean clone of an instance of class?

Comment: @Kossel how do I go about changing the function of a class in the test suite?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want: if you want global change, maybe you can use `instance.prototype.myFunction = anotherFunction` if you want to change the instance function then you can just do  `instance.oldFunction=anotherFunction`

Comment: what tools are you using for testing?